# Google.OrTools.dll not working in windows container

Tags: windows, docker, containers, or-tools

Google.OrTools are used in our application. When we deployed it in microsoft/iis image of windows container we are getting the below exception:

Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\NGECatCalcAPIServices\RulesDll\v3.0.2.7\Google.OrTools.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.--- at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
 at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)

We also installed VC++ runtime version 2017. Then we tried to deploy the latest Google.OrTools.dll (v6.10). But still getting the same exception.

Has anyone come across such a scenario. If yes how is it resolved?

Any help in this regards would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to copy all the dlls whose name starts with msvcr and msvcs which are present in c:\windows\system32 and c:\windows\syswow64 folders

Answer (score 2):

Can you check the IIS container is 64 bit?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But we need to run IIS in 32 bit as we have few components which will only run in 32 bit mode.

Comment: That's unfortunate. We dropped official support for 32 bit some times ago. I do not even know if the source code still compiles in 32 bit.  Can you run two IIS stacks, and have them communicate models and solutions?

Comment: What I found is Google.OrTools.dll depends upon Google.Protobuff.dll. Can you please help me with the path in which I need to copy this dll. I tried to copy in the same folder but its not working.

Comment: Do you use nuget?